# Setting time for pinging a IP in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ip, ping, child-process

hi i have a requirement to set time before pinging a app.Basically i'll have to reduce or increase the default time set.Below is my code

```
var sys = require('sys'),
exec = require('child_process').exec;


var pingCmd = "ping " + "127.0.0.1";
var result = '';

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
if (error) {
    console.log("error", "Error connecting");
    result = "Failed";
    console.log(result)
}
else {
    sys.puts(stdout)
    result = "Success"
    console.log(result)
}
```

}

```
exec(pingCmd, puts);
```

Below is my output

```
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Success
```

I'm stuck as how to set time.Any solution regarding this will be much helpful.

Comment: What time exactly do you mean? Time before starting the ping process? Time between pings? By now you're doing no more than forking a ping command as a child process utilizing node...

Comment: i meant time between pings

Comment: So - did my answer help you in any way...?

Answer (score 0):

**Quick solution**: As stated in your comment, you are looking for a way to influence time between packets to send. As long as you're choosing to create a child process, this is merely a question of how to parametrize the `ping` command. Using a command line shell you would go with:

```
$ ping -i 2 127.0.0.1
```

Time between pings is raised from one (default) to two seconds here by using the `-i` parameter. But you need root privileges to decrease the time to a fractional of a second:

```
$ sudo ping -i 0.1 127.0.0.1
```

**CAUTION!** Flooding a network with ICMP packets may have impacts on network availability and firewalls often value this as DOS attacks. Use `$ man ping` if familiar with the shell to gather more information about the ping command - "man" is always your friend when dealing with unix commands.

Your JS code of course has to be modified like this:

```
...
var pingCmd = "ping -i 2 127.0.0.1";
...
```

You also may create a child process for each ping request within a loop where you can control time of inactivity between process execution programmatically. You would then use `$ping -c 1`which causes the process to send only one packet.

**Alternatively** you may try out a native npm package like *[net-ping](https://www.npmjs.org/package/net-ping)*. This gives you more flexibility to influence ping behavior programmatically and you don't have to create child processes.